# Every arc of circle $|z|=1$ contains points s.t. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{n!}}{n+1}$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

The original question is the following:

> Show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{n!}}{n+1}$ has radius of convergence $1$. Show also that every arc of positive length on the circle $|z|=1$ contains points at which this series diverges. (Alan F. Beardon, *Limits - A New Approach to Real Analysis*, 1997)

The first question is easy for me

$\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{z^{n+1}}{n+2} \dfrac{n+1}{z^{n!}} = \displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} z^{n+1}$,

$\therefore z<1 \Rightarrow$ The series conv., $z>1 \Rightarrow$ The series div.

$\therefore$ ROC $ = 1$

However, what struggles me is the second question:

Here is my attempt, but I don't know how to do further:

Let $z=e^{i \theta}$

Then $\sum \dfrac{{e^{i\theta}}^{n!}}{n+1} = \sum \dfrac{e^{n! \theta i}}{n+1} = \sum {e^{n^n \theta i - \ln (n+1)}}$

Comment: What happens when $z$ ia a root of unity?

Comment: @Conrad ok. I know how to attempt this question now. (I typed in the answer). Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 1):

If $z$ is a root of unity, say $t$ ($1 = z^t$)
, then $\dfrac{z^{n!}}{n+1} = \dfrac{(z^t)^{\frac{n!}{t}}}{n+1} = \dfrac{1}{n+1}$, i.e. for such case, the series div.

$\forall q \in \mathbb{Z}: e^{\frac{q\pi i}{t}}$ is the solution of $1 = z^t$

$\because$ rational numbers are dense, $\therefore$ The statement holds.